# Why and when does the wrapper function call itself rather than the original_function passed to the decorator function?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-decorators

I'm a beginner at Python and I came across this issue while declaring decorators. I don't know what to call this specific scenario so I'm unable to google it effectively.

The scenario is that I declared 2 decorator functions, **decorating_function1** and **decorating_function2** and added them to my function named **original_function**. When I executed the original_function, it went into an infinite recursion. After debugging I found that the wrapper function of decorating_function2 was calling itself rather than the original_function that was passed to decorating_function2.

Furthermore, when I tried this code directly on the Python interpreter, it ran without any issues. (I'm unable to reproduce this scenario in the interpreter)

So, my question is, is there a specific scenario that can result in this type of behavior?

Code snippet of what I was trying to do. The code below runs correctly:

```
def decorating_function1(original_function):
  print(original_function.__name__)
  def wrapper(*vargs,**kwargs):
    print('inside wrapper of df1')
    return original_function(*vargs,**kwargs)
  return wrapper

def decorating_function2(original_function):
  print(original_function.__name__)
  def wrapper(*vargs,**kwargs):
    print('inside wrapper of df2')
    return original_function(*vargs,**kwargs)
  return wrapper

@decorating_function2
@decorating_function1
def original_function(name,age):
  print("Name of the person is %s and his age is %d" % (name,age))
```

EDIT:
I haven't been able to reproduce the scenario. I was using Emacs when this issue had occurred. I've tried to reproduce this issue with other editors and the python interpreter in vain. So, I'm assuming this issue is not that major and shouldn't be possible normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me fine, so I'll address the question about the calling order here.

You may have heard that "stacked" decorators are called "bottom-up". What does this mean?

When your call `original_function`, then `decorating_function1` is called with the function as the argument. Now, this returns `wrapper`. Then, you have `decorating_function2` "stacked" on top of `decorating_function1` after this finishes.

Hence, `decorating_function2` is called with an argument of `wrapper`. Then, this executes... so `wrapper` inside of `decorating_function2` is executed which in turn calls `decorating_function1`'s wrapper which then calls `original_function`.

So, it looks like this:

original_function (e.g. original_function(age, name) )

i) decorating_function1 -> returns "wrapper"

ii) decorating_function2(wrapper) -> returns "wrapper"

wrapper for ii) executed which is calling i)'s wrapper hence, i) 
    is executed and this calls original_function

If you were to add the extra bit "decorating_function1/2" before `original_function.__name__` in your wrappers you would see this:

```
Decorating function1 original_function
Decorating function2 wrapper
inside wrapper of df2
inside wrapper of df1
Name of the person is (a name) and his age is (a age)
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the function calling order. The thing I wanted to know was when can the wrapper of decorating_function2 call itself instead of the original_function passed to decorating_function2. I'm unable to reproduce the scenario after I re-wrote the code snippet.

Comment: It's hard to answer that without seeing the code you had previously.